# expected primary-expression before 'int' shows up when calling a function. How to fix?

Tags: c++

Trying to call a function, error shows up saying that it requires a primary-expression. How to solve?

Function is all about getting user input and putting it into an array list. This is just a small part of a whole code, I am testing out the parts so I can debug it more easily.

This is the error that shows up:

15  23  C:\Users\asus\Desktop\TERM 2\CS107-8L\tester.cpp    [Error] expected primary-expression before 'int'

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;


void getInput(int list[],int dim);


int main()
{

    
    cout<<"enter number: "<<endl;
    getInput(int list[], int dim);

    
}


void getInput(int list[], int dim)
{       
    for(int i = 0; i<20; i++)
    {
        cout<<"loc["<<i<<"] ";
        cin>>list[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should define the arguments and then pass them into the function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's is no `list` and `dim` defined in your code.

Second, VLA-arrays are not valid in C++. You should use `std::vector<int>` instead:

Third, in `main()`, you call `getInput()` like this:

```
getInput(list, dim);
```

So, your code should look like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

void getInput(std::vector<int>& list);

int main()
{
    int dim{};

    std::cout << "enter number: " << '\n';
    std::cin >> dim;
    
    std::vector <int> list(dim)

    getInput(list);    
}


void getInput(std::vector<int>& list);
{       
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "loc["<<i<<"] ";
        std::cin >> list[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using **incorrect syntax** to call the function `getInput`.

**Moreover** inside your `main()` function there is no object named `list` or `dim`. So you must first create an object named `list` and `dim` and then pass those as arguments to the function `getInput` as shown in the example given below.

If you want to take the size of the array as input then `std::vector` would be a better choice since the size of a built in array must be a **compile time constant** in c++.

With `std::vector` you can do what you want as shown:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//no need to pass the second argument since we can use std::vector::size
void getInput(std::vector<int>& list);//getInput is a function that takes a listtor by reference as argument


int main()
{

    int dim = 0;
    cout<<"enter number: "<<endl;
    std::cin >> dim;
    std::vector<int> list(dim);//create a vector of size dim 
    getInput(list);//call function

    
}


void getInput(std::vector<int> &list)
{       
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)//note i have used list.size()
    {
        cout<<"loc["<<i<<"] ";
        cin>>list[i];
    }
}
```